# Проблемы с backgroundworker

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Добрый день, не могу разобраться что произошло с backgroundWorker, точнее, до определенного момента он у меня работал(другие потоки работают без проблем), но сегодня он перестал вообще определятся отладчиком, то есть при его вызове отладчик не переходит в тело backgroundworker5_dowork а пытается отловить любое иное событие в программе,делает это успешно, пробовал пересоздать backgroundworker5 и запустить на другой машине, но результат не меняется, да и в самой программе алгоритм записанные в тело не работает, вот пример кода

```
        private void button52_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            backgroundWorker5.RunWorkerAsync();
            this.button52.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void backgroundWorker5_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {...}
        private void button51_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (backgroundWorker5.IsBusy)
            {
                backgroundWorker5.CancelAsync();
            }
            else return;
        }
```

в чем может быть проблема и как ее решить

> MainForm.Designer.cs

```
this.backgroundWorker5 = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
this.backgroundWorker5.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
this.backgroundWorker5.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker5_DoWork);
private System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker5;
```

Comment: "_при его вызове отладчик не переходит в тело backgroundworker5_dowork_" А он и не должен, метод-то выполняется в другом потоке. Просто поставьте там breakpoint.

Comment: нет в backgroundworker5_dowork стоят breakpoint, он должен по любому его перехватывать, но этого не происходило да и сам код как я писал выше не работал, а нашёл проблему в инициализации пространства имен библиотеке в  backgroundworker5 находились классы библиотеке и по этому его вообще не запускал, какой то глюк VS2012, сейчас я исправил все работает, самое странно что и ошибку он не выдавал

Answer (score 1):

проблема при инициализации пространства имен библиотеки в программе, классы которой содержал backgroundworker5, решил удалением ссылки на библиотеку и обратным добавление в проект, видимо что то заглючило в конфигурациях, самое подлое отсутствие ошибки